# Migrating on premises application to Azure Cloud query

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine, deepzoom

We are in the process of moving into Windows Azure blob storage several thousand Seadragon image-pyramids that are currently stored in our on-premises SQL Server database.  We use Microsoft’s Deep Zoom Composer library (deepzoomtools.dll) to initially create the image tiles.  But since Deep Zoom Composer (DZC) generates the tiles in a hierarchy of folders, we subsequently traverse the directories DZC creates in order to harvest the image tiles.

But now we are trying to figure out how we can publish our image-tile-pyramids directly into Azure blob storage.  We tried to decompile the DeepZoomTools DLL to see if we might redirect its file system calls to Azure blob storage.But this task proved rather difficult and in consequence we are looking for another approach.

So for time being we have a virtual machine in Azure to leverage DeepZoomTool.dll and publish to the virtual machine’s hard drive.  From the VM’s hard drive, we can then harvest the tiles using a Window Service and put the tiles into Azure blob storage.  But this approach necessitates that we manually maintain both the virtual machine and the widows service.  And it also has some other drawbacks as well.  So we’re looking for a better approach.If you guys have any other alternative method or can offer any helpful suggestions, we would certainly appreciate your insights!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider having the Windows service as a worker role. Through the worker role, you can create local temporary storage whereby your application can store it's images. once done, the worker role can go through them and upload them to Blob storage.

If you do it this way, you will not need to worry about the maintenance of the VM as it's a PAAS not IAAS.

Comment: Don't you think this approach will be costlier in terms of Azure pricing ?